# Windows 7: Extending the command line prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

Is it possible to extend the windows cmd prompt, by *prepending* a string to the current prompt?

If I would use bash, I would write something like
   PS1="XXX $PS1"

Is there a similar possibility for the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

`PROMPT "String %PROMPT%"`

The current prompt is stored, as you may have guessed, in the %PROMPT% environment variable. Using that in the prompt command will keep the existing prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
set "PROMPT=XXX %PROMPT%"
```

See also:

- `PROMPT /?`
- http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Custom-Windows-Command-Prompt

Comment: That does not preserve the current prompt, though. It appends the system default prompt to the string. What if the prompt has already been changed to something?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!

The prompt is also available using the environment variable PROMPT.

Hence I can do a

set PROMPT=XXX %PROMPT%

Comment: Did not I suggest the same?